# `git log -p path/to/file` doesn't show all the changes

Tags: git, git-log

I expect it to show all the changes (commits) to the specified file, but it doesn't do that. It shows only some of them. I suppose it has something to do with merging, but I don't see what might go wrong here. Can someone explain that?

**UPD** I was able to reproduce my particular issue in a test repo:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
rm -rf 1
mkdir 1 && cd 1
git init

mkdir 1
echo m1 > 1/m1 && git add 1/m1 && git commit -m m1

git co -b b1
echo m11 > 1/m1 && git add 1/m1 && git commit -m b11
echo m1 > 1/m1 && git add 1/m1 && git commit -m b12

git checkout master
echo m2 > m2 && git add m2 && git commit -m m2
git merge b1 -m 'merge b1'
git --no-pager log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
git --no-pager log --oneline 1
```

Commits `b11` and `b12` are not listed by the last command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I basically more or less answered my question, trying to reproduce the issue in a test repo. In my case, it happens when, say, feature branch changes a file, but then restores it to the state it was in. That is, when merge as a whole doesn't introduce changes to the file. Not sure why this happens, however. But it must have something to do with [history simplification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) thing.

Answer (score 4):

Use `git log -m -p`.  You may also want to add `--follow` if you are looking to track renames (the `--follow` code is pretty hacky and only works for certain cases, and I have no idea how it behaves if the rename point occurs in a merge).

By default, `git log -p` shows you nothing for merge commits, even when you ask for specific path(s).  The `-m` flag effectively tells `git log` to split each merge commit into two<sup>1</sup> virtual commits, one against each parent.  It then shows changes against each parent, at which point you will see changes to the specified path(s).

(Note: using `git show` on merge commits will by default show combined diffs, including when looking at specific path(s).  Combined diffs suppress files that do not have changes versus both/all parents, so `-m` may also be useful here.)

As [DavidN's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37465297/1256452) notes, add `--all` (or `--branches`, `--tags`, and/or `--remotes`) if you want to look at all references (or all branches, all tags, etc.).

For particularly complex cases, see `git for-each-ref`, which can generate ref-names that you can filter and then pass on to a `git log` command.

---

<sup>1</sup>Assuming the merge has only two parents—if there are more, the merge is split into *N* effective commits, i.e., *N* such virtual commits.  You can identify each virtual commit by the fact that its commit ID is no longer a normal SHA-1 hash.  Instead, it is a pair of hashes: the merge's ID followed by the specific parent's.

Answer (score 1):

Throw in an --all flag? `git log --all filePath` By default, log only follows back from current branch. You can list all branch names on the command `git log branch1 branch2 -- filePath` or the `--all` flag considers all possible branches.

Comment: Indeed, this way it works, but the changes I'm talking about were done long in the past. That is, I'm not talking about commits, that are in the branches that exist now. It's as if `--all` switch used this way makes `git` follow all the paths. Without it, it chooses only some of them.

Comment: Not following you. One other option might be how the clone was done, its possible to specify a --depth argument when you clone a repo that limits the history that it fetches. If you do this, then you also may not see the complete history as its not in your cloned repo.

Comment: "That is, I'm not talking about commits, that are in the branches that exist now."  Are they in branches _that exist now_ or are they _in the current branch_?  `--all` includes not just commits in the current branch, but any branch _that exists now_.  (Commits not in any branch are garbage and not shown, ever.)

Comment: I see, it worked with `--all` because of stale remote-tracking branches. After pruning them, `--all` doesn't help anymore.

If it had to do with partial cloning, `--all` wouldn't help.

"That is, I'm not talking about commits, that are in the branches that exist now." Sorry, by "branches that exist now" I meant those parts of them, that branch from the main trunk (master..BRANCH).